# How do I force my Graphite Airport to distribute 192.168.x addresses instead of 10.x.x addresses?

Tags: airport

I'm sharing a single IP address but there's no way to change what network it uses for distributing the private addresses via DHCP. My problem is that my VPN to work already uses the 10.x.x network, so I'd like my home to use 192.168.x.

I've tried messing with the Network tab within the Airport Admin Utility for Graphite and Snow but nothing works. I'm hoping there's some way to hack the configuration file.

Comment: Usually these 10.x networks use a netmask of 255.255.0.0 (/16), so it shouldn't matter, as long as the second part is different...

Comment: yes it shouldn't matter, but only because the VPN connects to a public internet IP.  if your 10.x.x was the same as your company's 10.y.y, you could still be in trouble despite netmasks IF you were tryng to initiate the VPN to a 10.y.y address -- your VPN initiation would never make it past your router.  but since your system won't see the company's 10.y.y until after the VPN's connected, it won't matter (because the 10.y.y in your packets to the VPN are encrypted and won't be seen by your router).

Answer (score 0):

Should be under the network config tab I actually found a picture of it.

[image]

How old is that thing?

Comment: Yep, that looks like it should work, but it doesn't. When I try to use it, it tells me that the Airport requires a static IP. I think it assumes another device is running NAT when used.

Comment: Reading the descriptions on those options are very interesting.  Are there any firmware updates for it?

Comment: It has the latest firmware, but at this point the issue might be moot. My Vista box couldn't use the DNS server provided by the Airport and it doesn't perform as well speed wise as the Mac Mini that was providing Internet access. I've updated the Airport to just be a WAP for now. Thanks.